# " rely on it " vs " put it on"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, morphology

1. rely on it
2. put it on

At times I feel confused about usage of some phrasal verbs ending with an adverb or a preposition. Just like the above two examples, the usage of "on" is different. Some prepositions can serve as adverbs; it is difficult to distinguish between them. Are there hints?

How do I know if "on" is a preposition or adverb in those two examples?

Comment: _Rely on [something]_ - put your reliance on it. _Put [a garment] on_ - put it on yourself.

Comment: @Cascabel, Noted with thanks. I just want some more similar examples just like " go over it" vs " think it over",  for dictionaries or grammar books only list some.

Comment: Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary is quite helpful on this topic...I think Cambridge has published a Phrasal-Verb dictionary. I got one here somewhere, unless I lent it out.

Comment: Are you putting me on?

Comment: As @HotLicks demonstrated with her pithy comment/question above, the phrasal verb "put (direct object) on" has a variety of meanings, so you're going to have to be more specific and also provide some context since usage of "on" in "put (direct object) on" varies, like if I say, "Put it on," referring to a shirt, then all that's happening there is the indirect object is being left implied (i.e., the direct object of the preposition "on," which in this case would be "yourself"), but in Hot Licks' example, "on" has no direct object but truly is part of an idiomatic phrasal verb meaning "kidding."

Comment: @Cascabel, Noted with thanks.

Comment: Some transitive multi-word verbs are obligatorily separable, some MWVs are optionally separable, and some are inseparable. And different usages (meanings) may behave differently. One just has to learn their idiosyncrasies. The Oxford Book of Phrasal Verbs gives information on hundreds. // I'd call the adverby- or prepositiony- thing a 'particle' when part of such idioms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, You're right. For non-native speakers, it's difficult to know how phrasal verbs are correctly used far more than what they mean; especially some are used in idiomatic way. By the way, that's a good book; I will buy one.

Comment: The number of [sep oblig] MWVs is very small (other than with prepositional objects, eg *'_Spiggot_? Look up it in a dictionary'). // If you look up 'phrasal verbs' here, you'll find (1) why the term is considered hopelessly ill-defined by some, (2) classifications of V + particle/s examples (eg [trans insep] ... //// literal // transparently/opaquely metaphorical),  (3) where they grade into [V + PP] constructions (really murky, this one).

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth, Noted with thanks. I've ordered the Oxford Book of Phrasal Verbs. Moreover,  I will take a break and take time reading as many posts in this site as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this appears to be  too basic for this site...
Your main question seems to hinge on the usage of a particle  in a phrasal verb, and how to determine if it is an adverb or preposition.

***If it looks like a duck, but doesn't quack like duck, it ain't a duck.***

A [preposition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/preposition) requires an object; if it does not have an object then it is something else, probably an adverb.

Two examples  were provided, both using "on" in examples of parts of speech.

> rely on it
> put it on

***Rely on*** Sth/Sb

In this case, "on" is a preposition which can use almost any type of object.
You cannot say "*Rely it on me" because the object belongs to the preposition. It is not a separable phrasal verb. I would consider this to be an transitive verb + preposition combination, and possibly  not a phrasal verb at all. A similar structure is seen in the sayings...

> Lean on me,

and

> Depend on our leader.

***put on Sth/Sb***

...has several  meanings, and  the idiomatic intent can change depending on the object and its placement.

***Put on your clothes/Put them on***

...is an example of a separable phrasal verb that can take  an object either before *or after* the phrase. The object of the verb is "your clothes"...but the object can also appear *after* the preposition because the collocation  has an idiomatic meaning. The object of the preposition in this case is unstated but understood as  "your body", but other objects might include "a show", or a "song" and have different meanings.

And as Hotlicks has pointed out,

[***Put Sb on***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-sb-on)

is a very idiomatic usage that requires the object always between the two and seems to defy the rules...so go figure.